# How can optimize a query without repeat the value of the condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying do a optimization with cia_ensure_values without repeat the same condition for each cia_ensure

My tables:

```
|policies|
  |id|  |client|  |policy_business_unit_id|  |cia_ensure_id|   |state|       
   1      MATT                  1                   1             0
   2      STEVE                 1                   1             0
   3      BILL                  1                   2             0
   4      LARRY                 1                   2             1
   5      MATT                  1                   2             1
   6      STEVE                 2                   2             2
   7      BILL                  2                   2             2
   8      LARRY                 2                   2             1
   9      MATT                  2                   1             1

|policy_business_units|
   |id|   |name|  |comercial_area_id|
     1     LIFE         1 
     2     ROB          1 
     3     CAR          1 

|comercial_areas|
   |id|   |name|
    1      MICROSOFT
    2      APPLE

|cia_ensures|
   |id|   |name|
    1      ORANGE
    2      BT
    3      ATT
    4      MOVISTAR
    5      SPRINT
```

Here is the information:

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89491/1
```

I'm trying to create a query when it has values will repeat in my query

```
SELECT pb.name as unit,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v1, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a1, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v2, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a2, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v3, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a3, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v4, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a4, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v5, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a5, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n5 
  FROM cia_ensures ce 
  LEFT JOIN policies p on ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
  INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
  INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
  AND ca.id=1  
  Group by p.policy_business_unit_id;
```

The query is working fine without problems and showing this result:

```
 UNIT  V1  A1  N1   V2 A2  N2   V3  A3  N3   V4  A4  N4   V5  A5  N5
 LIFE  2   0   0    1   2  0    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
 ROB   0   1   0    0   1  2    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
```

But WHAT HAPPEN IF I HAVE 100 CIA_ENSURE? My query will be too long with more 100 lines.
How can I do creating a value @value where i type my cia_ensure and this will repeat like this:

```
  @cia_ensure_values = 1,3,5

  for ce.id=1,3,5

  /////This code will be repeated for all cias typed 
  SELECT pb.name as unit,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=@cia_ensure_values THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=@cia_ensure_values THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=@cia_ensure_values THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n,

  end              

  FROM cia_ensures ce 
  LEFT JOIN policies p on ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
  INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
  INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
  AND ca.id=1  
  Group by p.policy_business_unit_id;
```

Somebody can help me to optimize this query?

All kind of help will be accepted.

Please I will appreciate all kind of help.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. As you're finding out, the workaround is tedious, and hideously ugly, and not manageable. You'd be better off doing a plain normal "select *" and doing the rows->columns transformation in your client-side code when you retrieve the data. That or switch to a DBMS that DOES support pivot queries directly.

Comment: Like I said... do it client-side, switch to a different dbms that does support pivots, or be resigned to having huge/ugly queries.

Comment: If you insist on doing it with MySQL (which is inadvisable, as Marc B has noted), you'll have to use a cursor and a prepared statement, building the SQL of the query as you iterate through the rows of the cursor.

Comment: Okey that's an opinion but how can I do it on client side?

Comment: I guess it all depends on where your strengths lie. My strength is SQL, so I try to make client-side aps as dumb as possible and let the SQL do the heavy lifting. See my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this with a short prepared statement. Just include the ids you want in the `where id in()` clause:

```
select distinct @sql := concat('SELECT pb.name as unit,',group_concat(concat(
 'SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v',id,', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a',id,', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n',id)),
' FROM cia_ensures ce 
  LEFT JOIN policies p on ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id
  INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id
  INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id
  AND ca.id=1  
  Group by p.policy_business_unit_id;')
from cia_ensures
where id in(1,3,5);

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/631b56/23

Comment: SQLFIDDLE Question for anyone who knows: in the linked SQLFIDDLE, how do I get it not to display the results of the @sql variable assignment? Thanks.

Comment: Increased the max group_concat length: `set @@local.group_concat_max_len=10000;` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9adb8/17 I don't know what the max is, but you can increase it depending on the number of `ce.id` values you are passing.

Comment: The only way you are going to get dynamic columns in MySql is with a prepared statement since there is no pivot functionality. I would try to get that working. Here is a link to the manual on prepared statements. Perhaps the syntax is slightly different for your version:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: The only way you are going to get dynamic columns in MySql is with a prepared statement since there is no pivot functionality. Another option might be to hard code all the possible columns and hide the unwanted ones in your client side app.

Comment: Hey master your query saved my life =) thanks a lot for your help.
Thanks for all, i'm very happy with your help.